# angularjs (The output to be ten times)

Tags: angularjs

```
<html ng-app>
<body>
    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
        Starting:
        <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
            ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
        Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
    </form>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function StartUpController($scope) {
            $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
            $scope.computeNeeded = function () {
                $scope.needed = $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

The output to be ten times the value entered in the textbox... but not receiving any output.

Comment: Did you try $scope.needed = ( $scope.startingEstimate * 10 ) ;

Comment: Your scope names are in-correct funding.needed in HTML and needed in JS, change one of these !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startingEstimate` is not in the scope. It's in `funding`, which is itself in the scope.

And the template also looks for `needed` in `funding`, and not in the scope.

So the code should be:

```
$scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the expression :

```
<input ng-model="funding.startingEstimate" />
Recommendation : {{ funding.startingEstimate * 10 }}
```

no need to add controller code

Answer (score 1):

your code should look some like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/nisar_sql/sYWtS/

```
<body ng-app>
    <form ng-controller="StartUpController">
        Starting:
        <input ng-change="computeNeeded()"
            ng-model="funding.startingEstimate">
        Recommendation: {{funding.needed}}
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function StartUpController($scope) {
            $scope.funding = { startingEstimate: 0 };
            $scope.computeNeeded = function () {
                //$scope.needed = $scope.startingEstimate * 10;
                $scope.funding.needed = $scope.funding.startingEstimate * 10;
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
```